# Convert data into JSON format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have employee table. I have below fields. Few employees multiple mobile and home numbers. I want data in JSON format sending empid in where condition.

Select empid, empname, address, homenumber from dbo.emp

Values in these fields are

```
homenumber = 1^2^3^4
address = Home1^Home2^Office1^Office2
```

I want above data in below JSON format for all these fields - empid, empname, address, homenumber

I tried below query but getting wrong output

```
 select empid, r.value , r1.value from dbo.emp
      cross apply string_split (Homenumber,'^') r
         cross apply string_split (address ,'^') r1 where empid=1
```

I'm supposed to get data in below format

```
  "Address": [{"Homenumber": 1, "address ":"Home1"},{"Homenumber": 
     2, "address ":"Home2"},{"Homenumber": 3, "address ":"Home3"},
       {"Homenumber": 4, "address ":"Home4"}]
```

but since I have done cross join, it is getting more records. I would be great if someone can help me.

Comment: I would first suggest fixing your design if I am honest. Then worry about putting it into a different format.

Comment: That is the way we get data. Any help is really appreciate

Comment: It might be the way you *get* the data, but it shouldn't be the way you **store** it. Once you fix your design, the problem is simply to use `FOR JSON`.

Comment: What issue you see as a design?

Comment: The design issue is that you shouldn't ever store multiple facts together. Someone has 4 phone numbers? Ok, put each phone number in its own row.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `STRING_SPLIT` does not at the moment offer an `ordinality` column, so you cannot join the two splits on that.

Instead you can hack it by creating JSON and then using `OPENJSON`.

Finally combine it all together using `FOR JSON`, all inside a subquery

```sql
SELECT
  e.empid,
  (
    SELECT
      Homenumber = r1.value,
      address = r2.value
    FROM OPENJSON('["' + REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(e.Homenumber, 'json'), '^', '","') + '"]') r1
    JOIN OPENJSON('["' + REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(e.address, 'json'), '^', '","') + '"]') r2 ON r2.[key] = r1.[key]
    ORDER BY r1.[key]
    FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('Address')
  )
FROM dbo.emp e
WHERE e.empid = 1;
```

Comment: *"`STRING_SPLIT` does not at the moment offer an `ordinality` column"* It *does* on Azure SQL Database and 2022+

Comment: @Larnu I know, I did say "at the moment". 2022 is still in Preview, and OP does not indicate they are using Azure.

Answer (score -1):

```
select [data] from [table] for **JSON Auto**
```

will convert results into JSON format